# Annular region containing a zero

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Suppose $p(z)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ with coefficients either $ 1$ or $-1$ only. Is it possible to find a ring $1-f(n)< |z|< 1+f(n)$ containing at least one zero? I am not sure, whether such a function $f(n)$ can be established. I am sharing  a thought just came to my mind.

Answer (score 2):

For fixed $n$ the number of polynomials as considered in the OP is finite hence their number of roots is finite and zero is never a root. Assume $n \ge 2$ as otherwise problem trivial.

Take $f_1(n)=\min |z|, P(z)=0$ for some $P$ as above, then $0<f_1(n) <1$ (product of roots is $\pm 1$ and for $n \ge 2$ not all polynomials considered have roots only on the unit circle),

If $|w|=c \ge 2, |P(w)| \ge c^n-c^{n-1}-...-c-1 \ge 1$ as $c \ge 2$ so all the roots are inside the circle $|z| <2$ and if $f_2(n)=\max  |z|, P(z)=0$, it then satisfies $1< f_2(n) <2$ for the same reason as above (in degree $2$ or higher not all polynomials considered have roots only on the unit circle and the product of them is still $\pm 1$)

So the roots are in-between $f_1(n) \le |w| \le f_2(n) <2, 0<f_1(n)<1$ so one can take an annulus as required containing all the roots by taking $0<f(n)<1, f(n)=\max (1-f_1(n), f_2(n)-1) +\epsilon$, for some $\epsilon >0$ small enough